# Docker compose install error 'curl: (56) OpenSSL SSL_read: SSL_ERROR_SYSCALL, errno 104' in Ubuntu

Tags: docker-compose, installation, ubuntu-18.04

I am trying to install docker compose on the `Ubuntu 18.04.2 LTS`. 
I tried installing using the official link [here](https://docs.docker.com/compose/install/) and followed the Docker Compose documentation given, but when i run the command

```
sudo curl -L "https://github.com/docker/compose/releases/download/1.24.1/docker-compose-$(uname -s)-$(uname -m)" -o /usr/local/bin/docker-compose
```

then after some time it gives me this error

```
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
100   617    0   617    0     0    613      0 --:--:--  0:00:01 --:--:--   613
 24 8280k   24 2056k    0     0    789      0  2:59:06  0:44:27  2:14:39     0

**curl: (56) OpenSSL SSL_read: SSL_ERROR_SYSCALL, errno 104**
```

Kindly help me on this i have tried many times but it is not working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same problem. I assume that you are using [Docker Docs](https://docs.docker.com/compose/install/), which are usually outdated. You should go to [Docker Compose Github](https://github.com/docker/compose/releases) instead.

**Solution**

**1** - Open Linux Terminal by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>T</kbd>

**2** - Install **curl**:

```
sudo apt install curl
```

**3** - Turn on **root** privileges in terminal for your user (something like **admin** in Windows OS), with command:

```
sudo -i
```

**4** - Go to [Docker Compose Github](https://github.com/docker/compose/releases). In releases you will find this code. Run it in your linux terminal.

```
curl -L https://github.com/docker/compose/releases/download/1.25.1-rc1/docker-compose-`uname -s`-`uname -m` -o /usr/local/bin/docker-compose
chmod +x /usr/local/bin/docker-compose
```

**5** - Turn off **root** privileges in terminal for your user, with command:

```
exit
```

**6** - Check if **docker-compose** is installed with command:

```
docker-compose version
```

**Outcome:** In your terminal, you should see **docker-compose version number** and some other informations.