# curl: (56) OpenSSL SSL_read: SSL_ERROR_SYSCALL, errno 104

Tags: linux, curl, docker-compose, installation, ubuntu-18.04

**curl: (56) OpenSSL SSL_read: SSL_ERROR_SYSCALL, errno 104** error while installing a docker compose on ubunu:18:04
I refered:
[Docker compose install error 'curl: (56) OpenSSL SSL_read: SSL_ERROR_SYSCALL, errno 104' in Ubuntu](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58855156/docker-compose-install-error-curl-56-openssl-ssl-read-ssl-error-syscall-er)  but not working .Giving same error

Answer (score -1):

**Step1:-**
Instead installing using curl use following command.Change the current version of docker-compose (exp :1.25.4)

> sudo wget https://github.com/docker/compose/releases/download/1.25.4/docker-compose-$(uname -s)-$(uname -m) -O /usr/local/bin/docker-compose

**step2:**:Apply executable permissions to the binary:

> sudo chmod +x /usr/local/bin/docker-compose